# Autocomplete in CMD.exe from psexec

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, psexec

I am not sure if this is the best place to ask. But I am just wondering if it is possible to have autocomplete in `cmd.exe` / `powershell.exe` spawned by `psexec.exe`?

For example:
`psexec \\127.0.0.1 -u user -p pass cmd.exe`

Will spawn a cmd.exe on remote server, but autocomplete will not work.

I have also tried with different flags, `/F:ON` but have no luck.

I am happy to write my own script and do it if needed.

Comment: Have you found a solution for auto-completion?